# Plotting data from multiple data sets on a single plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have two data sets - one is a simulations for 100 IDs with 1000 data points each. The other is actual data with minimal observations. I want to overlay the observed data set on my prediction. The prediction shown as mean with 95% CI. i want to superimpose the observed data onto this.

I have tried `par(new=T)`, keeping scale, limits, labels same

error message:

```
ggplot(data = s1, aes(x = IVAR, y = DV))+ 
  stat_summary(geom="ribbon", fun.data=mean_cl_normal, 
               fun.args=list(conf.int=0.95), fill="lightblue")+
  stat_summary(geom="line", fun.y=mean, linetype=1,color="red",size=1)+ theme_light()+xlim(0,168) #data to show simulations with the CI band

par(new=T)

ggplot(data = s2, aes(x = IVAR, y = DV))+xlim(0,168)
par(new=F)
```

Comment: Do you want to add the second dataset as points?  You can add a layer using a new dataset to your first plot.  Like `+ geom_point(data = s2)`.

Comment: `par` doesn't do anything for grid graphics like `ggplot`.

Answer (score 1):

#### create dummy data

```
a <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 2:11)
b <- data.frame(j = sample(1:100, 10), k = sample(1:100, 10))
```

#### Plot both data frames:

```
ggplot(a, aes(x, y))+
  geom_point(color = "red")+
  geom_point(data = b, 
             aes(x = j, y = k), 
             color = "steelblue")
```

The key to the second `geom_point` call is the `data =` part.